# Building a Google Maps Directions URL with waypoints (that aren't stops)

Tags: google-maps

I want to go from a place to another using a Google Maps Directions URL in the Google Maps Mobile App. This is from Lisboa to Porto, in Portugal :)

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/38.759741,-9.153736/41.1454953,-8.6108788/

As you can see, I only gave the origin and destination coordinates and it works.

In my final solution I would like to ask the Google Maps App for the same route, but forcing it to pass through a location (39.657293,-8.827500). This is not a stop so I I cannot treat it as a waypoint.

I saw several options in other posts but none is working for me.

Any thoughts?

Than you very much for you help

Comment: like? https://www.google.com/maps/dir/38.759741,-9.153736/'39.657293,-8.827500'/41.1454953,-8.6108788/@39.9493498,-9.9365814,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m3!2m2!1d-8.8275!2d39.657293!1m0!3e0

Comment: No @Mapperz. Enclosing a waypoint in '' doesn't solve the issue for me. I've tried it and it keeps interpreting it on the mobile google maps app, in directions mode, as a stop and not as a passthrough point.